# How to listen two micro services on same port in Node.js

Tags: node.js, microservices

I am new to micro service. I want to create one application with two micro services. But i don't know how to listen both (or more) micro services on a same port to make it as one application. 
Is there any good tutorial pages available in online ? Please suggest me any blogpost or tutorial pages or help me to create a application with two micro services.

I am trying to create a Bus booking application which has two services,

1. Bus Service (which gives bus names & availability)
2. User Service (which gives & connect user details with bus).

I created two this as two nodejs application. Now i need to know how to combine this two as one application (with microservice).for that i can't listen this to one port.

Comment: If your micro-services are meant to be separate processes, then you can't have multiple processes listening on the same port.  You could have one process that listens on the master port and then forwards relevant information to the other two processes.  If your microservices are not separate processes, then please add more info to your question that describes your architecture.

Comment: @jfriend00 For Practicing micro services with node.js. i am searching online for nodejs microservices tutorial. but i didn't get any tutorial online.

Comment: We need to know what micro service architecture you're using before we can help.  Your previous comment doesn't help explain that at all.

Comment: Asking for third party libraries or tutorials is considered off-topic on stack overflow and is not permitted.  The general idea here is that you describe a specific problem well enough that people can understand exactly what you're trying to do, then describe what you've done so far and where you got stuck and ask a specific question about what you need help with.  This is not an appropriate site for "How do I do X?" when you haven't already done a lot of research, worked on your own solution and are now asking for specific help on what you've done so far.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. My problem is how to listen to microservice in same port.

Comment: If you're not going to describe what architecture you are using for your microservices, then we simply cannot help.  Multiple processes cannot both listen on the same port.  That's a TCP-level limitation.

Comment: Then how can i create microservices. i didn't have any architecture. i am simply studying microservice for node.js. thanks for your patient @jfriend00

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117443/discussion-between-gopi-and-jfriend00).

Comment: A microservice is just a web service that does one thing well.  That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use one port, you need to have a way to distinguish between requests for each. If they were previously only identified by port number (instead of, eg, each having a different path or domain), you will have to change the access URL (or header) in some way.

Given that, you can use the npm module, express, to easily distinguish between any number of request types by interpreting the request.

you might have:

service1.com and service2.com both pointing to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2020. You could distinguish these by examining the request object.

Eg,

```
app.get(/.*/, function(request, response, next){
switch(request.headers.host){
    case 'service1.com':
        //some stuff
    break;
    case 'service2.com':
        //some stuff
    break;
}
});
```

Or, if it was domain.com/service1 and domain.com/service2

```
app.get(/service1/, function(){/*some stuff*/});
app.get(/service2/, function(){/*some stuff*/});
```